# How to add extra plugins with ng2-ckeditor?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ckeditor

I managed to install [ng2-ckeditor](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor) in an Ionic app.

Now I am struggling to add [youtube plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube) inside it

What is the correct way to add extra plugins? I can download locally the plugin but what do I need to do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by downloading CKEditor locally and add the extra plugin in the corresponding folder.

Answer (score 0):

The author has answered this issue in [this issue](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/29).

I think you can create a folder inside src/ folder from the Ionic's project and then you only have to configure the plugins path when you pass the options for the CKEditor.

Comment: Thanks, the sample code the author provides does not exist anymore. I added the downloaded plugin to src/assets/ckeditor folder. In index.html under the cdn line I added the path to the plugin like this :  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js"></script>. But when I try to load the plugin  (this.config.extraPlugins = 'youtube') I get an error in the youtube plugin.js (Cannot read property 'button' of undefined). I guess I'm doing something the wrong way...